# Is NSUserDefaults Not Efficient?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

In my iOS app, I have static string data that is displayed across multiple view controllers during the app's run time. I am using `NSUserDefaults` at the moment to store the data locally for later access, but I am questioning if this is the most optimal way to do things.

Alternatively, what if I had `secondViewController.swift`

```
let nameText  = ""
let nameLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameLabel.text = nameText
}
```

and in `firstViewController.swift` I did this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let secondVC = secondViewController(nibNamed: "secondViewController", bundle: nil)
    secondVC.nameText = "John Doe"
}
```

Would the above be most optimal in terms of keeping the data not stale?

Comment: NSUserDefaults are made to store small user data — it is not meant to pass information through the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, NSUserDefaults is intended to be used to store small amounts of information *between* runs of your app, rather than as a way to transfer data between view controllers.

You might want to read up on the [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) software design pattern, which is a way to get data out of your view controllers, and into a "model object", which can be shared by multiple view controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Would you mind if I started a private chat with you? I want to ask a slightly related question

Comment: Sure thing. I tried to set up a Stack Overflow chat, but it's hopeless. I'm @mbessey on Twitter, if you want to get in touch.

Comment: Thank you, I just sent a tweet